# Update image in the privileges page's "Access to Moderator Tools" section

Tags: feature-request, privileges, privileges-page

Am I the only one who thinks that the image in the [Access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) page looks very unprofessional? Are those really the best arrows we can come up with?

[image]

Comment: are you volunteering your services as a graphic designer?

Comment: You can edit the wiki yourself on the privileges page on meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) and it will be synced to other sites.

Comment: I'd probably only make it worse ;)

Comment: The free hand red arrow is a distant cousin of the FHRC ;-)

Comment: @Lix ...and of the [FHRS](http://i.stack.imgur.com/liojw.png "Free Hand Red Spot")

Comment: Yeah, those bug me too.